# Check if object is a Matrix

Tags: java, reflection

I need to test if an Object is a Matrix or Array.

For example I've got:

```
String[] array;
String[][] matrix;
```

I'm using:

```
private boolean isVector(Class<?> clazz) {
    return clazz.isArray();
}
private boolean isMatrix(Class<?> clazz) {
    return clazz.getSimpleName().endsWith("[][]");
}
```

But I don't want to use `clazz.getSimpleName()` because is very slow (almost 10% of my execution time according to JProfiler), is there another way to test if an Object is a matrix?

I can't use instanceof because it can be a matrix of any object.

Comment: ***But I don't want to use clazz.getSimpleName()*** any particular reason to avoid using what oracle gently developed for you?

Comment: Use `instanceof`?

Comment: why the downvote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If clazz is an array of Foo, then (a) `clazz.isArray()` will return true, and (b) `clazz.getComponentType()` will return Foo.class.

So, to find out if there are at least two array levels, the question you want to ask is: "is this class an array, and is its component class also an array." In Java:

```
clazz.isArray() && clazz.getComponentType().isArray()
```

To find out if there are exactly two (so it's not an N-dimensional array, for N > 2):

```
clazz.isArray() && clazz.getComponentType().isArray()
  && !clazz.getComponentType().getComponentType().isArray()
```